# Go map returns nil value even though value is present

Tags: json, dictionary, go, null

Assume `answers` below is a `map[string]interface{}` unmarshalled from a JSON string.

```
if baths, ok := answers["bathrooms"]; ok {
  bathsFloat := baths.(float64)
}
```

Somehow I'm getting a panic with `interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not float64`. How can this be possible when the presence check is true?

Comment: Post your `answers ` or at leat some kind of mock.

Comment: Because `"bathrooms"` does exist, and is `nil`. Please post a [mcve] if you need assistance figuring out _why_.

Comment: Answers look something like `{"bedrooms": 2, "bathrooms": 1, ...}`, and they're unmarshalled via `answers := make(map[string]interface{})` and `err := json.Unmarshal(answersString, &answers)`

Comment: I guess my question is then: under what circumstances would a JSON field unmarshall into a nil value?

Comment: @user1230611: please don't put code in the comments, edit your question to reflect what you're doing. What you've explained should work, so you need to provide an example that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ok` only tells if the key is in the map, whether the value associated with it is `nil` (or in general the zero value of he value type) or not is another thing.

See this example:

```
answers := map[string]interface{}{
    "isnil":  nil,
    "notnil": 1.15,
}

if v, ok := answers["isnil"]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("Value: %v, type: %T\n", v, v)
}
if v, ok := answers["notnil"]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("Value: %v, type: %T\n", v, v)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/euYvb9pC-u_X)):

```
Value: <nil>, type: <nil>
Value: 1.15, type: float64
```

If `answers` is the result of a JSON unmarshaling, then the value associated with a key in it will be `nil` if the value in the source is JSON `null`.

See this example:

```
var m map[string]interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"isnil":null,"notnil":1.15}`), &m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/H3hzCUWdSs_y)):

```
map[notnil:1.15 isnil:<nil>]
```